# Shopify API get Total Returns/Refunds

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am trying to get the Net Sales of orders of our Shopify store on daily basis. I can do it with the `Orders API`, but there seems to be a mismatch for the `refunds` returned by the API and the refunds/returns that show up in the dashboard. 
In fact, the API doesnt show any refunds for the orders at all but there does seem to be some amount deducted from the Total Sales of Orders which make the actual Net Sales for that particular day.

I can retrieve the orders for one day by this example URL. I iterate through all the orders and add up each Order's amount which gives an exact number of Total Sales which match up to the number in the dashboard. But this Total Sales value doesnt take into account the refunds/returns. 
`/admin/api/2021-07/orders.json?status=any&created_at_min=2021-08-17T00:00:00-04:00&created_at_max=2021-08-18T00:00:00-04:00&limit=250`

There is a `refunds` in the returned json for each order as well in the above call but that is empty for all the objects.
I have explicitly tried to retrieve the refunds as well by following API call but it also returns empty for all the orders.
`/admin/api/2021-07/orders/{order_id}/refunds.json`

You may have a look at the Dashboard Sales image for one day. Please note in this image, I can get the exact value for Total Orders from the API but can not retrieve a single refund/return for any of the order.

[image: Shopify Dashboard One-day Sales Image]

Would you be having an idea what are these Refunds/Returns shown in the Dashboard? If so, is there a way how can I accurately calculate the Refunds/Returns by the API as well, so I can accurately calculate the Total Sales for one day?

Answer (score 1):

You should be working with Transactions. Specifically, the refund transactions. An Order has many transactions. So given some order, you can get at the interesting transactions, and calculate your important values, like Net. I have aced this for many clients, as Shopify does not report this type of value very well. So I generate reports with Net, refunds, taxes, etc, providing much clearer guidance than the standard Shopify reports.

Comment: I have actually tried `transactions` as well(read your answer on another thread) and the total of Sales amount for all orders achieved by this method also equals the total number of Sales attained by the `orders`.

Comment: That is where I have tried to direct the question on how can I calculate the refunds/returns which the Shopify dashboard claims to show but the API doesnt show that. I will be glad to accept your answer if you can drop some insight on the aforementioned question. Thanks!

Comment: As I said, transactions contains refunds. What is so hard about adding them up, and then getting your totals? I can also tell you, if you trust the Shopify reporting 100% you are in for a surprise. Examine orders in detail yourself, and make your code work with orders you trust contain the good data (from API calls).

Comment: Also, using GraphQL it is trivial to download transactions, get the ones that are refunds and come up with a subtotal of that number.

Comment: I was concerned about the mismatch of API and dashboard numbers. But I think "if you trust the Shopify reporting 100% you are in for a surprise" clears this. Appreciate your input